# Allow OTA installation of iOS app from Jenkins?

Tags: ios, jenkins, testflight, ota

I have been using Jenkins to build iOS apps and then as part of the Jenkins job, upload them to TestFlight to allow OTA installation of the builds.

It seems that TF's parent company has been acquired and over the last few days, changes have happened, Android support is to be removed, and if you don't have the latest SDK installed in the iOS app you won't be able to submit builds, plus a few other changes.

The concern is that I'm going to find TF going away soon and I need an alternative.

Does anyone know if it's possible to include an html / php page as part of a Jenkins jobs' "Last Successful Artifacts" section. the page would just include the same OTA like link that TestFlight would provide. The idea being, an iOS device could go to that page, click the link and it would install the .ipa file, which is also displayed on the "Last Successful Artifacts" section for the job.